# QML - How to append an action to a signal handler?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have created a custom timer providing a pause function and elapsed time property. When triggered, `elapsedTime` is incremented by the 'interval' property amount. I already tested it and it works fine.

```
// CustomTimer.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Timer {
    property double elapsedTimeSec: 0.0

    interval: 100
    repeat: true

    onTriggered: elapsedTimeSec += interval/1000
}
```

I added it into an existing project as an separate QML file. Now I wish to append action to my `onTriggered` signal-handler to interact and toggle things in my main application. A little code for example:

```
Rectangle {
    Slider { 
        id: slider
        value: 0.2
    }
    CustomTimer {
        onTriggered: slider.value += 0.1    
    }
}
```

How can I do that without deleting already-existing, internal `onTriggered` handler (since those are necessary to the timer process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do that without deleting already-existing actions, since those are necessary to the timer process?

You shouldn't have to worry. The two signal-handlers are executed separately and simultaneously (theoretically). They coexist. So in your code, both the `onTriggered` handlers in `CustomTimer.qml` and the one nested under the `Rectangle` will be executed.

The sort of *overwrite* behaviour you're concerned about only occurs with properties. For example, the `CustomTimer` below will change the timer's interval from 100 to 500. Unlike slots, the value is propagated.

```
Rectangle {
    CustomTimer {
        interval: 500
    }
}
```